# Looping Through FQL Results from Stream Table

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i am using FQL to get data from the facebook streams table, however, im having a little trouble trying to loop through the array to display results i need. here is the code i am using:

```
if ($user){
      //fql query example using legacy method call and passing parameter
      try{
            $fql2 = "SELECT app_data 
                     FROM stream 
                     WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key 
                                          FROM stream_filter 
                                          WHERE 
                                          uid=".$user." 
                                          AND type='newsfeed') 
                     AND is_hidden = 0";

            $param2  =   array(
                              'method'    => 'fql.query',
                              'query'     => $fql2,
                              'callback'  => ''
                         );
            $fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param2);
      }
      catch(Exception $o){
            d($o);
      }
}

for ($x=0; $x<200; $x++) {
      d($fqlResult2[$x]['app_data']);
}
```

which returns arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [attachment_data] => {"name":"name in here",
                          "href":"url here",
                          "description":"desc here",
                          ......etc}
)
```

what i want to do is get the values from the 'attachment_data', such as name, href...etc

any ideas?

Comment: i suppose nobody knows then? =o(

Answer (score 1):

this is not a facebook related question... its a php question...
you are looking for the [php function - array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)...

> array_keys — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i managed to figure it out using json